# How do I register services in an Autoac module that rely on configuration values from an external file

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, autofac

I am using Autofac and dot net core to build a console app.

One of my services that I want to register is an API service that I have built. Its constructor takes some parameters that are values stored in a configuration file that I can access via the `ConfigurationBuilder` (registered at program startup).

How do I go about registering services whereby the constructor has parameters that are available in a `IConfigurationRoot`?

For example, the constructor of my service is:

```
public DearInventoryApiService(ILogger<DearInventoryApiService> logger, string baseUrl, string accountId, string applicationKey)
```

I am registering the container in my `Program.cs` as follows:

```
    private static void RegisterServices()
    {
        var collection = new ServiceCollection();
        collection.AddLogging(configure => configure.AddConsole());

        //register the autofac container provider
        var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();

        //register the default module
        containerBuilder.RegisterModule(new DefaultDependencyModule());
        containerBuilder.Populate(collection);
        var container = containerBuilder.Build();

        ServiceProvider = new AutofacServiceProvider(container);
    }
```

My `DefaultDependencyModule` will look like this:

```
public class DefaultDependencyModule : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Register(r => new DearInventoryApiService(r.Resolve<ILogger<DearInventoryApiService>>(), {base url here}, {account id here}, {application key here})).As<IDearInventoryService>();

    }
}
```

My issue with the above is I am unsure how to get configuration values into the module for registration?

Edit 1:

I have changed my Module to have the Configuration passed in. It works, but I am unsure if it is bad design or if there is something better?

```
public class DefaultDependencyModule : Module
{
    private IConfigurationRoot ApplicationConfiguration;

    public DefaultDependencyModule(IConfigurationRoot applicationConfiguration) => ApplicationConfiguration = applicationConfiguration;

    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        //dear inventory api service
        builder.Register(r =>
        {
            string baseUrl = ApplicationConfiguration["dearInventory:apiBaseUrl"];
            string accountId = ApplicationConfiguration["dearInventory:apiAccountId"];
            string applicationKey = ApplicationConfiguration["dearInventory:apiApplicationKey"]; ;
            var logger = r.Resolve<ILogger<DearInventoryApiService>>();

            return new DearInventoryApiService(logger, baseUrl, accountId, applicationKey);
        }).As<IDearInventoryService>();

        //register the application itself
        builder.RegisterType<CoreApplication>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you are not using dotnet core builten dependency feature?
Have a look: [click here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2#code-try-12)

Comment: @MuhammadOvaisHanif Because I don't want to.

Comment: @MuhammadOvaisHanif I've used Autofac before and it was simple to plugin, so going with Autofac. If you can tell me how this is possible with builtin, then I would change.

Comment: Hey @Lock Are the params values known inside `RegisterServices` context?

Comment: @ShaharShokrani they can be. See my edit with what I have done so far - not sure if it is bad practice?

Comment: [This is one of the FAQs.](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/injecting-configured-parameters.html)

Answer (score 0):

### Option1

Your edit looks good, but according to the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) I thinks its better to decouple between the `ApplicationConfiguration` access, and the `DefaultDependencyModule`.

```
public class DefaultDependencyModule : Module
{
    public string BaseUrl { get; set; }
    public string AccountId { get; set; }
    public string ApplicationKey { get; set; }

    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        //dear inventory api service
        builder.Register(r =>
        {
            var logger = r.Resolve<ILogger<DearInventoryApiService>>();

            return new DearInventoryApiService(logger, BaseUrl, AccountId, ApplicationKey);
        }).As<IDearInventoryService>();   
    }
}
```

And modify the `RegisterServices` with:

```
private static void RegisterServices()
{
    string baseUrl = ApplicationConfiguration["dearInventory:apiBaseUrl"];
    string accountId = ApplicationConfiguration["dearInventory:apiAccountId"];
    string applicationKey = ApplicationConfiguration["dearInventory:apiApplicationKey"];

    //register the default module
    containerBuilder.RegisterModule(new DefaultDependencyModule() {
        BaseUrl = baseUrl,
        AccountId = accountId,
        ApplicationKey = applicationKey
    });

    //code
});
```

### Option2:

```
public class DefaultDependencyModule : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        //dear inventory api service
        builder.Register((c, p) =>
        {
            string baseUrl = p.Named<string>("baseUrl");
            string accountId = p.Named<string>("accountId");
            string baseUrl = p.Named<string>("baseUrl");
            var logger = r.Resolve<ILogger<DearInventoryApiService>>();

            return new DearInventoryApiService(logger, baseUrl, accountId, applicationKey);
        })
        .As<IDearInventoryService>();   
    }
}
```

Resolve time:

```
string baseUrl = ApplicationConfiguration["dearInventory:apiBaseUrl"];
string accountId = ApplicationConfiguration["dearInventory:apiAccountId"];
string applicationKey = ApplicationConfiguration["dearInventory:apiApplicationKey"];

DearInventoryService service = c.Resolve<DearInventoryService>(
    new NamedParameter("baseUrl", baseUrl), 
    new NamedParameter("accountId", accountId), 
    new NamedParameter("applicationKey", applicationKey)
);
```